# MySQL Row Returned by AJax Displays in Single Cell

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

First post ever:

I'm building my first web application using HTML, PHP, and Javascript.

I am using Ajax to run a PHP script to query the database. I want to essentially display the values of the database in an HTML table. Currently the entire row being returned from AJAX is being displayed in a single  in the HTML.

PHP:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

//Include database connect script
include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM Table";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die ('Could not query database');

if(mysql_num_rows($results)){

    echo '{"testData":[';

    $first = true;
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($results)){
        //Cast Results to JSON Data type

        if($first){
            $first = false;
        }
        else{
            echo ',';
        }
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
    echo ']}';
}
else {
    echo '[]';
}
```

Javascript/HTML:

```
/* AJAX Call to Get Values from PHP that Quiers Database */
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  async:   true,
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'php/get_wgw_errors.php',
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
  {
           alert('An error occurred... Look at the console');
  },
  success: function(data,status)
  {
    createTableByJqueryEach(data);
    color_table();
  }
}); 
});

/* Build App Data Table */
function createTableByJqueryEach(data)
   {
     var eTable="<section class='mdl-grid' id='my-error-table'><div 
   class='mdl-layout-spacer'></div><div class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col-
  tablet 
    mdl-cell--10-col-desktop mdl-cell--stretch'><span class='mdl-layout-
 title'>
    {{App}} Test Table Dynamic </span><table class='mdl-data-table mdl-js-
 data-
   table mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-data-table--selectable'><div class='mdl-layout-
   spacer'><thead>"

  $.each(data,function(index, row){
// eTable += "<tr>";
// eTable += "<td>"+value['name']+"</td>";
// eTable += "</tr>";

eTable += "<tr>";
$.each(row,function(key,value){
  eTable += "<th>"+value+"</th>";
});
eTable += "</tr>";
  });
  eTable +="</tbody></table><div class='mdl-layout-spacer'></div>
  </section>";
     $('#eachTable').html(eTable);
   }
```

HTML:

`<!-- Start App Stats Table Section -->
   <div id="eachTable">Loading Test Dynamic Table</div>
   <!-- End App Stats Table Section -->`

Result:[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUb7s.png)

Comment: Why are you trying to generate JSON like that? Just get all your data in one array and use json_encode() once. Also, use PDO or mysqli, as mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? In my PHP script I am using json_encode().